# How do I say 'God help us and bless us' in esperanto

Tags: phrase-requests

Quite confused about how to say this correctly, 'God help us and bless us'.

Looked into using *helpas* or *helpi* but not sure. I guess the general idea I need to understand is how one correctly gives a direct instruction in Esperanto like e.g. 'feed the baby', 'please walk the dog'.

Comment: Imperatives end in "-u."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The translation is *Dio helpu nin kaj benu nin.*

"God bless you" is *Dio benu vin.*

Have a look also at [the Lord's Prayer](https://eo.wikisource.org/wiki/Patro_Nia) in Esperanto.

---

More generally, both instructions and wishes can be formed with the verb ending *-u*.

"Feed the baby" is *Nutru la bebon* and "Walk the dog" is *Promenigu la hundon.*

To say "please", use *bonvolu* + [verb ending with *-i*]. "Please walk the dog" is *Bonvolu promenigi la hundon.*

Comment: Would one say *bonvolu* when speaking directly to God though? I have no idea. Is *bonvolu* used with begging over all?

Comment: *Bonvoli* means something like "to be favourably disposed, to deign." Whether it's appropriate in prayers is more of a theological question, I think! An alternative translation of "please" is the tag *...mi petas*.